# Laravel Livewire: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uri')

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

Issues after newest update:

Livewire version 3.2.1

PHP version PHP 8.2

[image: Image Contains the Code where Exception is throwing]

Steps To Reproduce
After upgrading to newest version, I get this issue:

> [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.livewireScriptConfig["uri"]')
> (anonymous function) (livewire.js:491:113)
> Global Code (livewire.js:7589)

Just made Composer update. Here is the screenshot containing composer.lock file:

[image: composer.lock]

Comment: Please share all text content **in text form**. Also, is this problem really related to Composer itself?

Comment: This question is completely relevant and should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same error.
The issue was resolved by manually updating the livewire.js file(+ *livewire.min.js* and *manifest.json*), which is further defined in the AppServiceProvider's boot method.
The files can be found at *vendor/livewire/livewire/dist* directory.

```
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
            return Route::get('/vendor/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
        });
    };
```

PS: I moved my files there because they are not updated like in version 2. [GitHub PR](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/pull/6891)